# new Number() vs Number()

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `new Number()` and `Number()`? I get that `new Number()` creates a `Number` object and `Number()` is just a function, but when should I call which, and why?

On a related note, Mozilla says:

> Do not use a Boolean object to convert a non-boolean value to a boolean value. Instead, use Boolean as a function to perform this task.
>
> ```
> x = Boolean(expression);     // preferred
> x = new Boolean(expression); // don't use
> ```

Why is that? I thought the results were the same?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`Boolean(expression)` will simply convert the expression into a ***boolean primitive value***, while `new Boolean(expression)` will create a ***wrapper object*** around the converted boolean value.

The difference can be seen with this:

```
// Note I'm using strict-equals
new Boolean("true") === true; // false
Boolean("true") === true; // true
```

And also with this (thanks @hobbs):

```
typeof new Boolean("true"); // "object"
typeof Boolean("true"); // "boolean"
```

---

**Note:** While the wrapper object will get converted to the primitive automatically when necessary (and vice versa), there is only one case I can think of where you would want to use `new Boolean`, or any of the other wrappers for primitives - if you want to attach properties to a single value. E.g:

```
var b = new Boolean(true);
b.relatedMessage = "this should be true initially";
alert(b.relatedMessage); // will work

var b = true;
b.relatedMessage = "this should be true initially";
alert(b.relatedMessage); // undefined
```

Comment: and `typeof(Boolean("true")) === "boolean"`, while `typeof(new Boolean("true")) === "object"`.

Comment: "While the wrapper object will get converted to the primitive automatically when necessary" That's true, but somewhat misleading. Objects (including `Boolean` objects) always evaluate to `true` in a boolean context: `if (new Boolean(0)) { alert("Oops, 0 is true."); }`. To get the "expected" value, call `valueOf`: `new Boolean(0).valueOf() === false`

Comment: This js lib https://github.com/lordnull/dice.js returns a `new Number(..)` with various properties, along with the primitive value.

Comment: I'll provide a use case here. Our dependency library will call id.toArray() on a string id such as "1234". So we actually need to ensure that we pass an object and not a primitive string to it. Let me know if this case makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

```
new Number( x )
```

creates a new wrapper object. I don't think that there is a valid reason to ever use this.

```
Number( x )
```

converts the passed argument into a Number value. You can use this to cast some variable to the Number type. However this gets the same job done:

```
+x
```

---

Generally:

You don't need those:

```
new Number()
new String()
new Boolean()
```

You can use those for casting:

```
Number( value )
String( value )
Boolean( value )
```

However, there are simpler solutions for casting:

```
+x // cast to Number
'' + x // cast to String
!!x // cast to Boolean
```

Comment: Your shorthands may be _simpler_, but they are not as clear as using the Number/String/Boolean functions to do the same thing.

Comment: @Nigel True, but among JavaScript programmers, the `+` prefix for Number coercion is common and (from what I can see) preferred.

Comment: The person maintaining your code later on might not be as well versed in JS as you were. I moved onto a JS project and the "convert to number" shorthand confused me. Spent a couple of minutes on it before I figured it out. In 2019 there is no reason to use obscure shorthand when clearer alternatives are available.

Comment: @StormMuller a couple of minutes? More like a couple of seconds. What's more confusing is the fact that `Number` starts upper case, while JS' naming convention is camelCase for functions. Even more confusing is the fact that you _can_ call it with new, but don't have to. Exhibit A: This question.

Answer (score 20):

Always worth consulting [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm); from Section 15.7.1:

> When `Number` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.

Similarly, using `Boolean` as a function (15.6.1):

> When Boolean is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.

...which means that you consult Section 9.2 ("ToBoolean"):

> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:
>   
> `Undefined` = `false`
>   
> `Null` =  `false`
>   
> `Boolean` = The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
>   
> `Number` = The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
>   
> `String` = The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
>   
> `Object` = `true`

The difference between `new Boolean(value)` and `Boolean(value)` is basically that the former returns an object, but the latter returns a primitive per the above. This **matters**, because objects are truthy:

```
var b = new Boolean(false);

display(b);            // Displays "false"
if (b) {
  display("true");     // This is the path that gets taken, displaying "true"
}
else {
  display("false");    // This path does NOT get taken
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/igeni4) ...whereas you almost always want booleans for the purpose of testing them.

Answer (score 1):

case with `instanceof`

```
const a = new Number('123'); // a === 123 is false
const b = Number('123'); // b === 123 is true
a instanceof Number; // is true
b instanceof Number; // is false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Type conversion to primitive value    
const a = Number('42')
a === 42  // true
a.answer = 'You asked the wrong question'
a.answer // undefined

// Object
const b = new Number('42')
b === 42 // false
b.answer = 'Life, the Universe, and Everything'
b.valueOf() === 42 // true
b.answer // 'Life, the Universe, and Everything'
```