# javascript sum returning NaN error

Tags: php, javascript, nan

i have a javascript shopping basket, in which the sum is returning a NaN error,almost every time.
in the code i have

```
    $('#add-to-basket select').selectbox();
    $('#contents select').selectbox().change(function (e) {
        var product = $(this).parents('.product');
        var ppu     = product.find('.ppu').val();
        product.find('.price .wrapper .value').text($(this).val() * ppu);

        var total   = 0;

        $('.product .price .value').each(function (index, value) {
            total += new Number($(value));
        });

        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        form.ajaxSubmit(function () {
        });

        $('#total .value').text(total);
    });
```

i tried using parsefloatm but still it dosn't work...

Comment: i must say that when i refresh the page, the sum is displaying correctly

Comment: Yeah, I'm nitpicking. :)  But there's a serious point here -- an error will stop execution of your program.  NaN is at worst an unwanted value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(value)` gives you the jQuery-wrapped element, not the actual value.

You want `$(value).val()` instead if the elements are form inputs, or `$(value).text()` if not.

Also, instead of `new Number(...)` you should just use `Number(...)`, or even `+...`:

```
$('.product .price .value').each(function (index, value) {
    total += +$(value).val();
});
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719320/new-number-vs-number) for the difference between `new Number` and `Number`.