# Difficulty rounding up json object value to two decimal place in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am having difficulty converting val.distance to a round figure.

the value passed from the server for val.distance is 197.13572611205996. what i want to do is to round it to 197.13 or 197.14. before outputting it. If I run this it breaks the code, however when i run it without trying to round the figure it works.

```
 $.getJSON('http://localhost/locategas/pas-autofind.php?lat='+poslat+'&lon='+poslon+'&jsoncallback=?', function (data) {

 var output='<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';

$.each(data.david, function(key,val){

var MYDISTANCE = math.round(val.distance); 

output+='<li>';
    output += '<a href="#detailPage" onclick="showPost(' + val.stationId + ')">';
    output+='<h3>' + val.stationName + '</h3>';
    output+='<p>' + val.region + '</p>';
    output+='<p>' + val.city + '</p>';
    output+='<p>' + val.town + '</p>';
    output+='<p>' + val.email + '</p>';
    output+='<p>' + val.tel1 + '</p>';
    output+='<p>' + val.tel2 + '</p>';
    output+='<p>' + val.status + '</p>';
    output+='<p>' + MYDISTANCE  + '</p>';
    output+='</a>';
    output+='</li>';
}); // go through each post
output+='</ul>';
$('#ul-li-items').html(output);
$('#ul-li-items').trigger('create');
// lists all the posts   
 });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You could help by giving the exact error message that appears in your console

Comment: JS is case sensitive, try Math.round.

Comment: Also, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is valuable to mention here too, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(Number(8.2342342)).toFixed(2)
```

Edit: Purpose was casting therefore only **Number()** is required and not **new Number()**

reference:[new Number() vs Number()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719320/new-number-vs-number)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing your error message, but I imagine that

```
math.round(…)
```

should be

```
Math.round(…)
```

But this is only the first part of your problem, because `Math.round` will round to an integer, not to 2 decimal places.

galchen's answer is a simpler way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I tried galchen's answer and it works, thank you for helping. I have learn something today

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like"

```
var value=123.123456;
value=value.toFixed(2);
```

This should give you the value 123.12.