# JavaScript usage of new keyword and memory management

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-5

What is the basic difference between these two statements from the memory standpoint. Just want to know making objects with new does anything special about the memory allocation and garbage collection or both are identical.
I have to load a huge binary data to an array so want to have an idea.
Another question is can i force de-allocation of any memory from the JavaScript directly? like Gc.Collect() in c# or delete operator?

```
var x=8;
var y=new Number(8);
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: This probably contains the information you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: Don't use `new` to create primitives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719320/new-number-vs-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference: none.
As for forcing deallocation: no.

(you can set all references to null; but that may be an unnecessary hint to the GC)

Javascript is fully managed and doesn't provide an API like C# to "order" the GC to do stuff. Indeed, you may even find that some objects end up tied to the DOM and aren't deleted until their associated nodes are. And each browser is a different flavour.

Comment: if i have to de-allocate something there is no way of doing it??

Comment: In short, no. Welcome to managed memory. If the variable allocated to your giant dataset goes out of scope, the JS engine should free the memory. If you're unsure about it going out of scope, then set the variable to null, eg:

        var data = getSomeHugetData();
        /* do some processing here */
        data = null;

But this is typically unnecessary, unless you're assigning this data to be a variable in the global scope or attaching it to a DOM element.

(please excuse that the comments system doesn't allow clean formatting of code :/ )