# Javascript Compare Numbers

Tags: javascript, html

its my first time, so please be gentle. 
I wrote a simple number comparison a while ago. But the comparison gives back a "wrong" bool.

Heres my Code:

```js
var UpperLimit = document.getElementById("UpperLimit").value; 
var LowerLimit = document.getElementById("LowerLimit").value; 

if (UpperLimit < LowerLimit){
 alert("Upper Limit is smaller as the Lower Limit!")
 return false; //Exit Function
} else {

// **do something with the Upper and Lower Limit**

}
```

```html
Lower Limit:<input style=" margin-left: 15px;" class="Limit" id="LowerLimit" type="number">m³</input>
Upper Limit:<input style=" margin-left: 17px;" class="Limit" id="UpperLimit" type="number">m³</input>
```

If i (for example) enter 150 for Lower Limit and 1000 for the Upper Limit in HTML, the comparison give me back a "true" and shows the alert. 
I dont know where the error is, i guess JS is interpreting the value wrong but i dont know what to do.

Thanks for your help!

Caliban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value from the input is still returned so you must convert the input value to a number.

You can do it like so:

```
var UpperLimit = Number(document.getElementById("UpperLimit").value);   
var LowerLimit = Number(document.getElementById("LowerLimit").value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I thougth JS would allready know that the imput is a number. 
I guessed wrong!

Comment: @Caliban You're welcome. Mark it as the correct answer using the green tick if this answer has helped you. It helps other people who are coming to visit this question find the right answer faster.

Comment: I wanted to do it earlyer, but i needed to wait 10 Minutes befor Mark it ;) 
Again, thank you!

Comment: parseInt or parseFloat should be used, not the instantiator for Number class.

Comment: @BRO_THOM I see no new keyword, so the type of UpperLimit and LowerLimit will be a number not an object and thus I see no issue in using a Number ***function***. If this is not clear I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719320/new-number-vs-number).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value is of type string, even if you set the input type to `number`.

```
1000 < 150 = false;
"1000" < "150" = true;
```

to correct this, just cast your values to `Number` like:

```
var UpperLimit = Number(document.getElementById("UpperLimit").value);   
var LowerLimit = Number(document.getElementById("LowerLimit").value);
```

EDIT:

for reference why this happens to string comparison: [Why is one string greater than the other when comparing strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: if you want to parse to a number in javascript, please use `Number(...)` in favor over `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast value of input to number because it returns string

```
var UpperLimit = Number( document.getElementById("UpperLimit").value);  
var LowerLimit = Number( document.getElementById("LowerLimit").value);  

if (UpperLimit < LowerLimit){
alert("Upper Limit is smaller as the Lower Limit!")
return false;   //Exit Function
} else {

**do something with the Upper and Lower Limit**

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thougth JS would allready know that the imput is a number. I guessed wrong!

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this

```js
function compair()
{
debugger;
var UpperLimit = document.getElementById("UpperLimit").value; 
var LowerLimit = document.getElementById("LowerLimit").value; 
var isvalid=true;
   let regex = new RegExp(/[^0-9]/, 'g');
  
    if (UpperLimit.match(regex)) {
       alert("UpperLimit Must be a valid number");
         isvalid=false;
    }
     if (LowerLimit.match(regex)) {
       alert("LowerLimit Must be a valid number");
         isvalid=false;
    }
if (isvalid)
{
if ( parseInt(UpperLimit) < parseInt(LowerLimit)){
alert("Upper Limit is smaller then the Lower Limit!")
return false; //Exit Function
}
 else {
 alert("Lower Limit is smaller then the upper Limit!")
}
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
Lower Limit: <input style=" margin-left: 15px;" class="Limit" id="LowerLimit" type="text"/>m³ <br/>

Upper Limit: <input style=" margin-left: 17px;" class="Limit" id="UpperLimit" type="text"/>m³
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="compair()" value="Submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```