# Why doesn't `new Array(new Number(3))` produce an array of length 3?

Tags: javascript

When I write `new Array(new Number(3))` in the console, it produces an array of length 1 with that item being a `Number` object with `valueOf`=3. Why does the array constructor treat `new Number(3)` different to the primitive version of `3`?

1. Can someone link me to a standards doc where this `Array` behaviour is specified?
2. Is this something that I need to watch out for in general, or is it specific to the Array constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: [ECMAScript 22.1.1.2 `Array (len)`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-len) -> Step 7: _"If Type(len) is not Number, then ..."_ with `typeof new Number(3) === "object"`

Comment: This was also useful to understand that `new Number` (or `Boolean`) isn't really useful, since it wraps the plain scalar into an object: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4719320/500207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in `new Array(new Number(3))`, the parameter `new Number(3)` returns an `object` and not the `number`.

Where as `new Array(Number(3))` will work as `Number(3)` returns 3, the number.

Thanks to [@Andreas' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580398/why-doesnt-new-arraynew-number3-produce-an-array-of-length-3#comment92096026_52580398), here's the specification: [ECMAScript 22.1.1.2 Array (len)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-len)

> Step 7: "If Type(len) is not Number, then
>
> 1. Let defineStatus be CreateDataProperty(array, "0", len).
> 2. Assert: defineStatus is true.
> 3. Let intLen be 1.

Comment: Thanks! If you can edit in @Andreas' comment with the ECMAScript link, then I will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

[From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Parameters)

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer
>   between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array
>   with its length property set to that number

Instance of `new Number(3)` is not an integer(number).

```
Number.isInteger(3) // -> true

Number.isInteger(Number(3)) // -> true

Number.isInteger(new Number(3)) // -> false
```

Comment: It might be good to illustrate this by showing the results of calling `Number.isInteger()`: Namely, `Number.isInteger(new Number(3)) === false` but `Number.isInteger(3) === true`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks this will complete an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaScript console:

```
> typeof(3)
"number"

> typeof(new Number(3))
"object"
```

Thus both of the following produce single-element arrays:

- `new Array(new Number(3))`
- `new Array(new Date())`

because you are passing in an `object`, not a `number`.

(This is not directly answering your questions, but hopefully is providing clarity in any case.)

Answer (score 1):

Array can take either n parameters representing its elements, or a number with the array length ([syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax)).

> new Array(element0, element1[, ...[, elementN]])
>
> **elementN** A JavaScript array is initialized with the given elements,
>   except in the case where a single argument is passed to the Array
>   constructor and that argument is a number (see the arrayLength
>   parameter below). Note that this special case only applies to
>   JavaScript arrays created with the Array constructor, not array
>   literals created with the bracket syntax.
>
> new
>   Array(arrayLength)
>
> **arrayLength** If the only
>   argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and
>   232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length
>   property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of
>   arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values). If
>   the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown.

If you console log the following values, you will see that `new Number(3);` is not an integer.

```
typeof 3
"number"

typeof Number(3)
"number"

typeof new Number(3)
"object"
```

As `new Number(3)` is an object it thinks it's elementN scenario where you are passing the first element of the array.

If you use `new Array(Number(3));` however, this would work because `Number(3)` is of type number.

You can also refer to the definition of new Number() ([syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Syntax)):

> value
>
> The numeric value of the object being created.

It is clear that it is returning an object from this explanation. When you are doing Number(x), what happens is a type casting:

> In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the new operator), Number can be used to perform a type conversion.

This explains why Number(3) would work as it would be casting 3 (or "3") as a number.

```js
console.log(typeof 3);  // number
console.log(typeof Number(3));  // number
console.log(typeof Number("3"));  // number
console.log(typeof new Number(3)); // object


console.log(new Array(3)); // [,,]
console.log(new Array(Number(3))); // [,,]
console.log(new Array(Number("3"))); // [,,]
console.log(new Array(new Number(3))); // [{}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `new Number()` is a constructor that creates an object of type `Number`. If you initialise an array using it's constructor `new Array()` with an object it becomes a member of that array. If you initialise an array using it's constructor `new Array()` with a numeric value it will create an empty array of that size.

Just type into your console:

```
var n = new Number(3);
```

You get an object of type `Number` with a primitive value of 3, this is different from

```
var n = 3;
```