# When is the creation of Number objects necessary?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Before I used to construct a Number to perform operations like:

```
let a = 0, b = "6";

a += new Number(b); // otherwise with

a += b; // a string is created instead
```

But later on I've found that I can simply use the unary `+` (`+b` instead of `new Number(b)`).

Also `Number` is their own type so things like:

```
for(const a of new Array(new Number("3")).keys())
    console.log(a)
```

Doesn't even work properly - the above for loop will only print out zero once.

So what could be the situations in which constructing a `Number` object is the only choice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4719342/4949918 The only case is when you actually need an object to set property to. Otherwise using +b, parseInt(b) or Number(b) ( without the new) is the right choice

Comment: I think it's for conformity. If you call a method on numbers, they are converted to a `Number` object. So as number objects exist, it makes sense that there is a constructor for them, although the constructor is not particularily useful.